# Debug the errors in my simple 2-Player Tic-Tac-Toe coding?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I was trying to make a simple two player tic-tac-toe on NetBeans.

I created 6 Textfields, one 'pass' button, one 'new-game' button and one exit button.

The 'pass' button has all the power in the code. Instead of X and O of the game, I'm using any two integers say 1 for X and 2 for O.

[image: Game Screen]

Here is my code for the 'pass' button :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;

    a=Integer.parseInt((jTextField1.getText()).trim());
    b=Integer.parseInt((jTextField2.getText()).trim());
    c=Integer.parseInt((jTextField3.getText()).trim());
    d=Integer.parseInt((jTextField4.getText()).trim());
    e=Integer.parseInt((jTextField5.getText()).trim());
    f=Integer.parseInt((jTextField6.getText()).trim());
    g=Integer.parseInt((jTextField7.getText()).trim());
    h=Integer.parseInt((jTextField8.getText()).trim());
    i=Integer.parseInt((jTextField9.getText()).trim());

    if

    (
        // if the grid is empty

            ((((jTextField1.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField2.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField3.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField4.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField5.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField6.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField7.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField8.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
        &&  ((((jTextField9.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)

    )

    {
        jLabel1.setText("Let's Begin!");
    }

    else if  // if it isn't empty

                (    //if partially full
                ((((jTextField1.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField2.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField3.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField4.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField5.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField6.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField7.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField8.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)
            ||  ((((jTextField9.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== true)

                 )
                 {


            if
            (
                ((a==b)&&(b==c))
                ||((d==e)&&(e==f))
                ||((g==h)&&(h==i))
                ||((a==d)&&(d==g))
                ||((b==e)&&(d==h))
                ||((c==f)&&(f==i))
                ||((a==e)&&(e==f))
                ||((c==e)&&(e==g))
            )

            {
                jLabel1.setText("We have a winner!");
            }

            else

            {
                jLabel1.setText("Okay, Next Move!");
            }

                 }

    else if
    //it is completely full
    (
            ((((jTextField1.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField2.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField3.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField4.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField5.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField6.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField7.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField8.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
        &&  ((((jTextField9.getText()).trim()).isEmpty())== false)
    )

    {
        if
        (
            ((a==b)&&(b==c))
            ||((d==e)&&(e==f))
            ||((g==h)&&(h==i))
            ||((a==d)&&(d==g))
            ||((b==e)&&(d==h))
            ||((c==f)&&(f==i))
            ||((a==e)&&(e==f))
            ||((c==e)&&(e==g))
        )

        {
            jLabel1.setText("We have a winner!");
        }

        else

        {
            jLabel1.setText("Nobody wins. :(");
        }

    }

}
```

If you find this stupid, please tell me! I'm just an amateur.

Here is the error I get,

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at projet.pys.TEST.jButton1ActionPerformed(TEST.java:181)
at projet.pys.TEST.access$000(TEST.java:11)
at projet.pys.TEST$1.actionPerformed(TEST.java:50)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I'd really appreciate if you guys go through everything above, and help me with it.

Comment: Oof.  As I've recommended others before, I would highly recommend that you start off with some introductory Java material, such as Deitel's Java How to Program, so that you can have a better understanding of the code that you're looking at, and the basics of object oriented programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""  <-- empty string can't parse to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is happening when you call parseInt(). If you pass this method something that cannot be interpreted as an integer, it will throw the error you are getting. In this case, when the boxes are empty you are trying to parse an empty string, which is not allowed. Confirm that the boxes contain text that can be interpreted as an integer before calling parseInt().

On another note, it would be good if you try to extract some of the routines you have here into their own methods, like a checkWinner() method. Good luck, glad you're starting to get into Java.